# Given a ranked list of people, how can I split them into 2 balanced teams efficiently?

Tags: math, runtime

For example, I can have 4 people ranked **[1, 2, 3, 4]**. How can I produce two balanced teams **[1,4], [2,3]** efficiently (if possible, in linear time)?

By balanced, I want their sums to be as close as possible and their sizes to be equal (even pool) or differ by 1 (odd pool).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit

I was able to figure it out. There are a few cases and once I determine which category the list falls into, its a very straightforward pattern.

Comment: do you require an algorithm for this ??

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) with limitation on subset size.

It might be solved with dynamic programming in `O(n*Sum)` time (suitable if `Sum` has reasonable limit).

Goal is to get `Sum/2` value with `n/2 +-1` items.

---

For specific case of values in 1..n range:

N even: get pairs `(1,n), (2,n-1)...(n/2, n/2 + 1)`
N odd: get pairs `(2,n), (3,n-1)...((n + 1)/2, (n + 1)/2 + 1)` and add left `1` into any group

Comment: I was able to solve it after thinking for a while. It can be greatly simplified because the array is essentially meaningless (it is always 1,2,3,...n for n people) which gives us a straightforward pattern.
Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Ironic Man But what do your "4 cases" mean?